# When does the value of file descriptor become "-1"?

Tags: c++, linux, valgrind, file-handling

I have a multi-threaded program in CPP which has a logging function which is used in the entire code. A log file is opened in the main function using fopen() and this logging function writes to it the string passed to the logging function. Also the function checks for file size. If it is greater than some value, it closes the file using fclose() and opens a new file using fopen(). The question here is I have been seeing this error in valgrind logs "invalid file descriptor -1 in syscall write()". I want to know what are the possible reasons for the value of file descriptor becoming -1. I have also observed an "Invalid read/write" error on the lines where any operation on the opened file descriptor is done. This makes me feel that it is this value of file descriptor that may be causing this error. Any hints will be highly appreciated.

Comment: If open returns -1 its an error indicator as can be seen in man pages etc... If you use this "file descriptor" for read/write you haven't checked for error in the first place, which you should do. The reasons that open(...) fails can be many. If it happens "suddenly" i.e. the file path is valid, the permissions are o.k. and there's enough space on disk it is most likely that your process has too many files open. The OS has a maximum number of opn files per process.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that i am using fopen() and fclose() and not open() and creat().

Comment: Well other functions may use open/creat behind your back and may also not check wether they've got a valid fd. My guess is still that you have too many files open...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If multiple threads are using the same FILE* then there are a number of problems you could be hitting if there isn't a lock around all calls to fopen, fclose and fwrite. While you are re-opening the file there may be another thread attempting to write to it. fwrite also performs buffered writes and multiple threads operating on the buffer may cause memory corruption.

Comment: Both the answers helped me debug and solve the issue. It was indeed happening as there wasn't a lock implemented and when two different threads were trying to read it concurrently, the fd value got corrupted.

Answer (score 3):

Look at the open man page

---snip from the man page---------

```
RETURN VALUE
   open() and creat() return the new file descriptor, or -1 if an error occurred (in which     case, errno is set appropriately).
```

---

Clearly, your code is not checking for error condition on the file descriptor (-1) and going ahead with read/write, hence you are seeing error.

### Edit (explanation w.r.t fopen)

Every file you open is associated with a file descriptor (irrespective of the fact you are using fopen). Valgrind is tracking your system call traces (read/write). FILE* is just a wrapper over file-descriptor. So, the error statements related to "-1" fd still indicate that you are reading/writing on a file that's invalid (may be your process exhausted the max fd's to allocate) etc. To understand it, I would recommend doing a system call trace of your process using "strace". you'll see that "fopen" (user/library level api) internally calls "open" (system call).

Hope it helps!

Comment: Agreed but fopen() function returns a FILE pointer. Otherwise, NULL is returned and the global variable errno is set to indicate the error. Since fopen() returns a FILE* you can't expect it to return an error code in that pointer. The only "special" value for pointers is 0